# Replace '&' with an image using jQuery/CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, image-replacement

Is there a way I can change the basic text version of '&' and replace it with an image? I was thinking can we do it in jQuery? I don't want to use php for this.

Or is there a way to target it using css?

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain more ? i didn't get what you want?

Comment: @kobe - I want to swap the text version of an ampersand with an image or a font-face, to make it look prettier. An auto replace method would be useful for automation sites like blogging. A force.

Comment: ok got it now , thanks for providing more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do it like this (asuming you want to replace inside `#container` element):

```
var origText = $("#container").text();
$("#container").text(origText.replace(/&/g, "__img_mark__"));
var intermediateHtml = $("#container").html();
$("#container").html(intermediateHtml.replace(/__img_mark__/g, '<img src="ampersand.gif" />'));
```

We're doing it in 2 steps because we don't want ampersands in the html code to be replaced

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: @Edgar I don't quite get why you need to do this in two steps, if you don't mind, can you explain it to me please?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably search for `&` or `&amp;` and use the [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace it with your image.

Comment: Ok, whoever upvoted, thanks. I still don't get why this got downvoted :/